# What does this syntax mean "if (value is bool v)"?

Tags: c#, syntax

I have found this in the HelixToolkit.WPF.SharpDX examples [here](https://github.com/helix-toolkit/helix-toolkit/blob/develop/Source/Examples/WPF.SharpDX/DemoCore/Converters.cs):

```
public sealed class InverseBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is bool v)
        {
            return !v;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is bool v)
        {
            return !v;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't compile and I cannot understand this syntax. Google doesn't have explanation either. Can somebody explain please?

Comment: `value is bool v` returns true if `value` is convertible to a `bool` and stores the value in `v` otherwise it returns `false` and sets `v` to the default.

Comment: Thank you, as always, found it 2 secs after asking. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `is` keyword is part of C#'s pattern matching and allows you to check whether a variable can be converted to a specified type. If it can be, the expression is evaluated to true.

If you specify a variable name after the expression, like

```
if (obj is bool variableName)
```

the `variableName` variable (which is of type `bool` in this case) will be initialized using the value of `obj`. This allows you to work with a typed variable in the scope of the if statement, saving you from casting the initial `obj` variable every time you want to perform a type specific operation.

For more information, look into [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching#the-is-type-pattern-expression).

Comment: Got it 2 seconds after asking. But you beat me to it. The points are yours. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

The `is` statement performs a check if `value` can be cast to boolean. If the check is positive the value will be cast into the variable `v`.

Look here for more explanation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is

However, i dont see a reason why it does not compile. You would have to add at least the error message from the compiler for that.

Comment: No, `is` is NOT checking if `value` can be cast to boolean. You misunderstand what `is` does. See this dotnetfiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/fFHu3q. Note that the type `SomeTypeConvertibeToBool` can be cast to `bool`. But despite a `SomeTypeConvertibeToBool` object being castable to `bool`, it cannot be pattern-matched against the `bool` type if the the variable is of type `SomeTypeConvertibeToBool` (compile error). (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) Even if you remove the offending code and try stuffing the `SomeTypeConvertibeToBool` object into a variable of type `object` and then pattern-match the `object` variable against the `bool` type (basically what the code in the question does), it will not match. Because a `SomeTypeConvertibeToBool` instance IS NOT a value of type `bool`. (Disclaimer, i downvoted your answer due to the misinformation stated therein.)

Comment: Side note: Your link leads to the the German documentation, instead of the English documentation. You might want to fix that, too.